# jquery - .split is not a function

Tags: jquery, split, attr

I am using the same code in some other place, which is working fine. but now i am using it, but is throwing me error i.e. **.split is not a function**

Below is code i am using:

```
var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
```

I have checked in Console, class name is coming like **Cls_abc-XYZ** and i want to get "**abc-XYZ**" from it. 
Any suggestion

Comment: are you getting class attr? log it?

Comment: yes.. right @Nirus

Comment: are you getting a string?

Comment: @Nirus yes... i am getting string like Cls_abc-XYZ. and i want to get abc-XYZ from it

Comment: No space character appears at `.className` of element, adjust `RegExp` to `/_/` `var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/).split(/_/).pop()`

Comment: @guest271314, bro if you check my question carefully then you will come to know.. Split is issue. split is coming as function i am not getting why..

Comment: Can you include `html`, full `javascript` at Question reproduce issue at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: *"I have checked in Console"* - How? Are you saying that `console.log($(this).attr('class'))` *immediately* before the line shown in the question will log a string value? If the element doesn't have a `class` attribute then `.attr('class')` will return `undefined`, resulting in the error in question.

Answer (score 1):

**split** is a string function.

your syntax is correct but what is **$(this)** 
You can log `$(this).attr('class')` value on console you can see this value does not `string`.

**forExample**

```
$('body').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
```

*returned array object  ["boxed","pattern-5"]*

Comment: yes.. bro that is the issue, i know and it should work like you told. but it is not.. that i am not getting why... is there other issue you can tell.. what could be the cause for it

Answer (score 0):

fixed it as below:

```
$('body').attr('class').toString().split(/\s+/);
```